# Webapp appcache: Do I need to include app icons and startup images

Tags: html5-appcache, iphone-web-app

I have an WebApp that works offline on iOS and Android. In the head of the HTML it references a lot of icons for the different sizes. And it also references a startup-image.

All these images are not used in app itself. I try to minimize the network traffic and also the number of files to download at startup.

So do I need to reference the icons at all in the appcache manifest?

Comment: Any update? Solution?

Comment: I got no definite answer. I don't think that we need to include the icons, because the icons are independent and are needed when the bookmark the user creates the bookmark. so I removed the icons from the manifest. I'm not sure about the startup image.